# Is it unsafe to invoke a function by it's name as a string using the window object?

Tags: javascript

Would you please tell me if there is anything unsafe, in the JS of a standard web page, about invoking a function by it's name as a string using `window['function_name']()`?  I remember reading something about it quite some time ago but cannot locate it now.

I thought there was a reason to not use the window object to do so, because to invoke functions between a background script and content script in a web extension, I always declare a different object in each and declare the functions that can be invoked in this manner as properties of the object and pass the function names as strings in the communication port to invoke them; but I cannot remember why.

Thank you.

Comment: In JavaScript, `foo.bar` and `foo[‘bar’]` are equivalent statements.

Comment: The only reason would be in case your code runs in an environment that doesn't have a window object. But you could always start with `var window = typeof window == 'object'? window : this;`.

Comment: I think more context is required to answer your question. The code that is being invoked can be insecure if its something injected by a user but it sounds like you own the code being invoked. Server side should never trust client side requests without some sort of authentication and authorization. I've never heard of invoking a function on window by string as an insecure operation.

Comment: Thanks. The function name would be a variable of type string; so, the dot reference wouldn't work but that's not the point.  I must be remembering something incorrectly.  I thought there was some warning I read about it but it seems to make no sense why there would be. Perhaps it had only to do with the extensions I was working on at the time.

Comment: I own the code and it will be part of an extension, injected once and never invoked via the background script but only by user action in the web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which context your running the code,

**1. JS Execution Context**

Its fine to use string as function name and call the corresponding function residing in an object.

```
const functionName = "someFunction";
window[functionName]()
```

But If string is part of a `untrusted data` or `user controllable string` then it not safe to use. i.e Reading a string from a url parameter.

**Example**:

```
const unTrustedUserInput  = window.location.hash
window[unTrustedUserInput]();
```

**2. web Extension BG & CS Context**

As per [chrome recommendation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/security), you should not trust the message received from content-script. You should always sanitise the input and place necessary validation before executing it.

So, I would recommend not to pass function name as string, instead use a dictionary map with corresponding guid to validate to which function the call is made.

**Example:**

```
// cs context

chrome.extension.sendMessage({ id: "<GUID-1>", data: "data" }, (response) => {
// handle response if any
});
```

```
// BG context
var CSBGCommunicationMap = {
"<GUID>-1": window.someFunction
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
   if (sender.id !== "<varlidate id-ur-Extension>" && sender. origin !== "<validate origin>") {
   // Early return if it comes from malicious content or unknown sender
   return;
  }

  if (message.id && message.id in CSBGCommunicationMap) {
      const functionToBeCalled = CSBGCommunicationMap[message.id];
     // functionToBeCalled(message, sendResponse);
  }

});
```

I hope this clarifies your concern.

Comment: @Gary Does my answer clarifies ?

Comment: Thanks for the link to the recommendations for extension secrutiy.  I was not aware of some of these issues. I don't see how making an id for a function name helps. All of the code sent to the page is visible and can be deciphered. The event listener that triggers the messages to the BS and CS will make it clear what the function requested is to do. It's difficult to protect. Unless the code is locked up, there's always somebody smarter than me that can ruin it if they really want to. But it is something to think about and can at least make it as difficult as possible to decipher.

Comment: Thanks @Gary. using an ID for a function is useful, for instance if there are private function which is handling sensitive information in BG, which you don't want ur CS to be called. But if an attack controlled page-script somehow take control of your CS (some loophole), instead of calling the actual function, it might call ur private function and access the sensitive information. Having said that, a comprised system can't be fully protect. But at the same time, following these good practise helps to tighten the security will prevent in leveraging some of the attacks.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), The `Window` object is a global object which contains the entire `DOM document`. So if you call a function `foo()` (without specifying any object), Javascript will search it in `window object`.

**In other hand**,

`foo()` , `window.foo()` and `window['foo']()` are same. But when talk about `security`, Let's say if user injects some malicious code into the function `foo`,
doesn't matter you invoke the function `foo()` or `window['foo']()`, The injection will effect both.

**Avoid using Window object**

You don't need to specify the `window object` to call a global scoped functions or variable unless, it shadowed by your current scope.

```js
function x() {

   console.log('hey i am global');

}

function y() {

  function x() {
     console.log('I have power only inside y()');
  }

  x(); // I have power only inside y()

  window.x() // hey i am global

}
```

And If you don't handle `window object` properly, There are lot of chances to get run-time errors and the entire object will be collapsed.

Comment: "You don't need to specify the window object to call a global scoped functions or variable" - you _do_ need to use `window` if whatever you're wanting to access (be it a function, variable, constant, etc) is shadowed by another name in the current scope.

Comment: Yeah. you are right, I updated my answer. Thank you!